# How do I create a custom web service with soap in a custom module?

Tags: 7, hooks, services

I try to make custom webservice, begin from nothing no working, now i try to services.

I create the soap server in this form

Install service module and soap_server dev module.

Create webservice soap

[image: create-service]

create api service

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ctools_plugin_api().
 */
function core_custom_webservice_ctools_plugin_api($owner, $api) {
  if ($owner == 'services' && $api == 'services') {
    return array(
      'version' => 3,
      'file' => 'my_module.services.inc'
    );
  }
}
```

later create own service in core_custom_webservice.services.inc

```
function core_custom_webservice_services_resources() {
  $resources = array(
    'core_custom_webservice_resources' => array(
      'actions' => array(
        'response_word' => array(
          'help' => t('Response of webservice'),
          'file' => array(
            'type' => 'inc',
            'module' => 'core_custom_webservice',
            'name' => 'core_custom_webservice.resource',
          ),
          'callback' => 'core_custom_webservice_get_response',
          'args' => array(),
          'access callback' => '_node_resource_access',
          'access arguments' => array('view'), 
          'access arguments append' => TRUE,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
  return $resources;
}
```

and later core_custom_webservice.resource.inc

```
function core_custom_webservice_get_response($response) {
  return 'print '.$response;
}
```

Later i visit resources in ui admin services, and enable my own resource

[image: own resource]

and later visit link of my service, the link is /endpoint_path

[image: error service endpoint]

and later i try to debug visit url /soap_server/debug_wsdl/endpoint_name

make this xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:tns="urn:soap_server" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="soap_server" targetNamespace="urn:soap_server">
  <types>
    <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:soap_server"/>
  </types>
  <message name="core_custom_webservice_resources_soap_response_word_request"> </message>
  <message name="core_custom_webservice_resources_soap_response_word_response">
    <part name="response_object" type="xsd:struct"/>
  </message>
  <portType name="soap_server_port_type">
    <operation name="core_custom_webservice_resources_soap_response_word">
      <input message="tns:core_custom_webservice_resources_soap_response_word_request"/>
      <output message="tns:core_custom_webservice_resources_soap_response_word_response"/>
    </operation>
  </portType>
  <binding name="soap_server_binding" type="tns:soap_server_port_type">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <operation name="core_custom_webservice_resources_soap_response_word">
      <soap:operation soapAction="urn:xmethods-delayed-quotes#core_custom_webservice_resources_soap_response_word"/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal" namespace="urn:xmethods-delayed-quotes"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal" namespace="urn:xmethods-delayed-quotes"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
  </binding>
  <service name="soap_server_service">
    <port name="soap_server_port" binding="tns:soap_server_binding">
      <soap:address location="http://192.168.11.37/core/soap"/>
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
```

and later of this, i dont know how i can make, please any solution, i try to make all step by step for make this functional.

this is my client

```
<?php

$echo = $_GET['input'];

print "<h2>Echo Web Service</h2>";
print "<form action='client.php' method='GET'/>";
print "<input name='input' value='$echo'/><br/>";
print "<input type='Submit' name='submit' value='GO'/>";
print "</form>";

print "</form>";

if($echo != ''){
    $client = new SoapClient(null, array(
      'location' => "http://192.168.11.37/core/soap",
      'uri'      => "urn:soap_server"));

    $result = $client->__soapCall("core_custom_webservice_resources_soap_response_word",array($echo));

    print $result;
}
?>
```

Comment: Also do you want this inside a block?

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to put that into Drupal - why do you need to? You're not using the API, you need to bypass the normal request workflow, it's just not a good fit

Comment: You're much better off using the Services module. It's extremely well built. Why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: Hi @Jaypan How can construct this in services, with custom methods and soap

Comment: Here's the module: https://www.drupal.org/project/services, here is the documentation, https://www.drupal.org/node/109782, and here is the SOAP server that integrates with it: https://www.drupal.org/project/soap_server

Comment: Hi @Jaypan i create with services and soap_server but i dont know how, i make the step by step for this new question